# Choose 1 person out of 8 per week, 13 weeks, each person chosen $1 \leq x\leq3$ times

Tags: combinatorics

We have 13 weeks (meaning order matters), and for each week we have to pick a person, out of 8 people. each person must be chosen $1 \leq x\leq3$ times.

We didn't study inclusion-exclusion or any more advanced techniques yet.
I'm looking for a hint on how to approach this, so I'd rather you don't post just a solution.

Comment: $1\ge x\ge 3$ doesn't make sense

Comment: @J.W.Tanner thanks, fixed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

Since each person has to be chosen atleast once, can you take care of (any) $8$ weeks out of $13$, while remembering that order matters? Now for the remaining five weeks, make cases:

$$\bullet \text{two people chosen twice and one person chosen once}  \bullet \text{one person chosen twice, and three people chosen once} \\ \bullet \text{five people chosen once}$$

Comment: Thanks, this is the solution i got to if anyone is interested:
$\binom{13}{8}8!(\binom{8}{5}5!+\binom{8}{3}\frac{5!}{2!2!}+\binom{8}{4}\frac{5!}{2!})$

Comment: @reggiN That’s almost correct, it’s also important to distinguish a person based on how many times they get chosen. So there should be a ${8 \choose 2 }{8\choose 1}$ instead of $8 \choose 3$, and ${8 \choose 3} {8 \choose 1}$ in place of $8 \choose 4$.

Comment: I think I see your point, but then you could pick the same person twice which beats the purpose of separating to cases, no? maybe you mean $\binom{8}{2}\binom{6}{1}$?

Comment: Yes, that’s what I meant.